# Extracting hue range from an input image

Tags: c++, opencv

How to extract hue range from an input image ? I want to extract hue low and hue high from an image in order to use it in matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the image to HSV colorspace, then split it into its 3 channel components, and then find the minimum and maximum values from the hue channel:

```
Mat img = imread("c:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg");

Mat hsvMat;
cvtColor(img, hsvMat, CV_BGR2HSV); // Convert image to HSV colorspace

vector<Mat> hsvChannels;
split(hsvMat, hsvChannels); // Split the HSV image into the 3 channels

Mat hue = hsvChannels[0]; // This is the hue image

// Find minimum and maximum hue
double minHue = -1;
double maxHue = -1;
cv::minMaxLoc(hue, &minHue, &maxHue, nullptr, nullptr);

cout << "Min hue=" << minHue << " Max hue=" << maxHue << endl;
```